# How to get user' info on MS Teams bot - Node.Js

Tags: visual-studio, bots, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to get user's infos when they send a new message to the bot on Microsoft Teams, but I'm new on this things and cannot do it for myself, need some assistance step-by-step.
Can you help me with this ?
And, how can I use this infos during de code ?

I've did the bot, and I'm showing cards with buttons to them with some options that are receiving from QnAMaker, now, i wanna get those infos to in the future make a connection with AD and do some things.

I expect to get users' infos from the chatbot on MS Teams and use this during the code.

Answer (score 0):

@Murilo Teixeira You could fetch the users information using [Context for Bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-context#nodejstypescript-example). Here is a [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node/blob/master/src/dialogs/examples/teams/FetchRosterDialog.ts) which fetches the user information.

Comment: I know, but I can't integrate this with my bot, I've to know how can I do it with my qnaBot.

Comment: I'm programming on Node.Js